# Order of compilation in ant target

Tags: java, ant

The `ant` `compile` target below compiles all `.java` files in any of the `src` folders specified using a `<src path="..."/>` tag. My question is about the order of compilation. Does `ant` first compile the files referenced by the first `src` tag (i.e. does it first compile the Java files in `${xtext.project.path}/src`), then the second `src` tag, etc.? What order are the files compiled in? I'm trying to figure out the dependencies between folders and wonder if the order they are listed tells me anything.

```
 <target name="compile">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>

        <deps-load-path conf="core"   pathid="core.ivy.classpath" />
        <deps-load-path conf="test"   pathid="test.ivy.classpath" />

        <javac debug="true" includeantruntime="false" debuglevel="source,lines,vars" destdir="${bin.path}" source="1.8" target="1.8">
            <src path="${xtext.project.path}/src"/>
          <src path="${xtext.project.path}/src-gen"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/src"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/src-gen-umpletl"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/src-gen-umple"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/test"/>
          <src path="${vendors.path}/jopt-simple/src"/>
          <exclude name="**/.git"/>
          <exclude name="**/*.ump" />
          <exclude name="**/data" />
          <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
          <classpath refid="validator.project.classpath"/>
          <classpath refid="core.ivy.classpath" />
          <classpath refid="test.ivy.classpath" />
            <!-- Add compiler arguments here, see https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg for details, example below
                  <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation" />
            -->
        </javac>

        <copy todir="${bin.path}" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${project.path}/src"><include name="**/*.grammar"/></fileset>
            <fileset dir="${project.path}/src"><include name="**/*.error"/></fileset>
        </copy>
        <delete file="cruise.umple/src/rules.grammar"/>
        <delete file="cruise.umple/bin/rules.grammar"/>
      </target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how `<javac>` compiles files by running Ant with the `-verbose` option.

For example, the following Ant script...

```
<javac debug="true" includeantruntime="false">
    <src path="src1"/>
    <src path="src2"/>
</javac>
```

...outputs the following with `ant -verbose` running on a Windows machine...

```
[javac] Compilation arguments:
[javac] '-classpath'
[javac] ''
[javac] '-sourcepath'
[javac] '.....\src1;.....\src2'
[javac] '-g'
```

In the above example, Ant combined the `<src>` elements into the semicolon-separated `-sourcepath` argument.

`-sourcepath` is an option of [Oracle's `javac` tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> -sourcepath sourcepath
>
> Specifies the source code path to search for class or interface definitions. As with the user class path, source path entries are separated by colons (:) on Oracle Solaris and semicolons on Windows and can be directories, JAR archives, or ZIP archives.

Note the distinction between Ant's `<javac>` task and Oracle's `javac` tool. The Ant `<javac>` task calls the Oracle `javac` tool.

For your question "What order are the files compiled in?", the answer is essentially: The Java files are all compiled at the same time.

Comment: I wonder if you can answer one other question. `project.classpath` is defined elsewhere in the file as the same location as `${bin.path}`, which is where the compiled files are written to. How can `${bin.path}` be both a classpath dependency and the location where `.class` files are written? I know for a fact that `${bin.path}` gets deleted before each build, so there isn't anything in the folder prior to the `compile` target being run. Are the `.class` files that are produced as the `compile` target executes added to the `classpath`?

Comment: I made another question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913499/classpath-and-ant-builds