# classpath and Ant builds

Tags: java, ant

The ant compile target below compiles all .java files in any of the src folders specified using a `<src path="..."/>` tag. You can see that a number of items are added to the `classpath` using `<classpath refid=...>` tags.

```
<target name="compile">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>

        <deps-load-path conf="core"   pathid="core.ivy.classpath" />
        <deps-load-path conf="test"   pathid="test.ivy.classpath" />

        <javac debug="true" includeantruntime="false" debuglevel="source,lines,vars" destdir="${bin.path}" source="1.8" target="1.8">
            <src path="${xtext.project.path}/src"/>
          <src path="${xtext.project.path}/src-gen"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/src"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/src-gen-umpletl"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/src-gen-umple"/>
          <src path="${project.path}/test"/>
          <src path="${vendors.path}/jopt-simple/src"/>
          <exclude name="**/.git"/>
          <exclude name="**/*.ump" />
          <exclude name="**/data" />
          <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
          <classpath refid="validator.project.classpath"/>
          <classpath refid="core.ivy.classpath" />
          <classpath refid="test.ivy.classpath" />
            <!-- Add compiler arguments here, see https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg for details, example below
                  <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation" />
            -->
        </javac>

        <copy todir="${bin.path}" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${project.path}/src"><include name="**/*.grammar"/></fileset>
            <fileset dir="${project.path}/src"><include name="**/*.error"/></fileset>
        </copy>
        <delete file="cruise.umple/src/rules.grammar"/>
        <delete file="cruise.umple/bin/rules.grammar"/>
</target>
```

One of these items is `project.classpath`, which is defined elsewhere in the file as the same location as `${bin.path}`, which is where the compiled files are written to (see the `<copy todir...>` tag). How can `${bin.path}` be both a classpath dependency and the location where `.class` files are written to? I know for a fact that `${bin.path}` gets deleted before each build, so there isn't anything in the folder prior to the compile target being run. Are the `.class` files that are produced as the compile target executes added to the classpath dynamically?

Comment: The class files are written to the **destdir** and if the same directory was included in the classpath, it wouldn't matter. The classpath is used to create the class files, to provide any classes that might be missed from the source .java files.

Comment: So the `destdir` is on the classpath, and `destdir` is populated with `.class` files as compilation proceeds. Does that mean the `classpath` is changing dynamically (i.e. as `destir` is filled with `.class` files)?

Comment: That seems like a weird way to do it, though. What happens if `A.java` requires `B.java`, we go to compile `A.java`, and `B.java` hasn't yet been compiled? Would the compiler skip `A.java`, then after compiling `B.java` and putting `B.class` in `destdir`, return to `A.java`? Seems like a dependency nightmare.

Comment: This is no longer an ANT question, but about how the Java compiler works. Let's take the simple scenario first. If the java files under compilation only referenced classes in other java files, then there would be no need for a classpath, correct? All the classes would be available locally. The classpath is used to link to classes that are external to the source code, typically in 3rd party jar files. Managing those jar files is the real dependency management challenge. Hence the need for ANT plugins like ivy emulating capabilities in Java build tools like Maven and Gradle

Comment: Ok, what if I were to compile each folder that's included in a `<src path...>` element separately? Would I need to put folders that contain the `.class` files from the other folders on the `classpath` in order to compile properly (since the other folders would be considered external to the java files in the folder being compiled)? Is the rule "if you reference java classes with `.class` files outside of the folder you're currently compiling in, you must add the files that contain the external classes to the classpath"?

Comment: Simply put, what does it mean to be "available locally" when it comes to Java compilation? Maybe I could change my earlier questions and say I have a subproject named `A` and a subproject named `B` that `A` depends on.

Comment: Yes I would rewrite or resubmit the question as it stands it's hard to understand the problem you're trying to solve. If you have a complex multi-component project, I would consider splitting it up into smaller builds.